# display 'welcome " customer_name"' at the top of the magento site

Tags: magento, authentication, header

when customer login to site, it should display "welcome customer" at top of the site.

assume customer will login to site. after customer login, in top of the site there

should be a some message to welcome customer.

how to display welcome " customer_name" at the top of the site.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome message is default in ver 1.9

Comment: but it's not displaying in our site.... http://demo.kidsdial.com

Comment: Try this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/how-do-i-change-the-welcome-message-in-magento-1-9-the-proper-way

Comment: hi @Slimshadddyyy, thanks  a lot , there was a welcome message was missing in header.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check following code must be there :

In header.phtml file

```
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

In page.xml file block should be there :

```
    <block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
        ..........
        <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
    </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //LOAD MAGENTO 
require_once 'YOUR_PATH_TO_MAGENTO/app/Mage.php'; 
umask(0); 
Mage::app('YOUR_WEBSITE_CODE', 'website');

//GET SESSION DATA 
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); 
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend')); 

$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->$session->id);

//CHECK IF LOGGED IN 
if($session->isLoggedIn()){ 
echo 'Welcome ' . $customer_data->firstname . " " . $customer_data->lastname; 
} else { 
echo "Welcome guest"; 
}

- See more at: https://www.jnorton.co.uk/blog/magento-check-if-customer-logged#sthash.bxeDgV9U.dpuf
```

Comment: hi @mokiSRB thanks a lot for reply. there was welcome message missing in header.phtml file.

Comment: hi, thanks.... yes what i did is i added this code in header.phtml file = > <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p> solved it.... is what i done is  right?